# I can't sort after using getFilter()

Tags: java, android, listview

My java file is: This file contain searching and sorting in Listview, but sorting do not work after using searchbar, the problem i found is that the code :adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence) when i removed it, the app works fine but filtering is not done. So the proble is that line. is there any way to do searching and sorting in listview?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public List<String> galaxies=new ArrayList<>();
boolean ascending = true;
/*
- When activity is created.
 */
private Button sortBtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mListView);

    //REFERENCE MATERIALSEARCHBAR AND LISTVIEW

    MaterialSearchBar searchBar = (MaterialSearchBar)  
    findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    searchBar.setHint("Search..");


    galaxies.add("Cartwheel");
    galaxies.add("Whirlpool");
    galaxies.add("Andromeda I");
    galaxies.add("Andromeda II");
    galaxies.add("Sombrero");
    galaxies.add("Messier 81");
    galaxies.add("Messier 87");
    galaxies.add("Canis Majos Over-density");
    galaxies.add("Messier 92");
    galaxies.add("Black Eye");
    galaxies.add("Centaurus A");
    galaxies.add("Centaurus B");
    galaxies.add("Milky Way");
    galaxies.add("IC 1011");
    galaxies.add("Star Bust");
    galaxies.add("Hoag's Object");
    galaxies.add("Pinwheel");
    galaxies.add("Triangulum");
    galaxies.add("Cosmos Redshift");
    galaxies.add("Ursa Minor");
    galaxies.add("Virgo Stellar-Stream");

    //ADAPTER
    final ArrayAdapter adapter=new 
    ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,galaxies);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    //SORT
    sortBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sortBtn);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    sortBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ascending)
            {
                Collections.sort(galaxies);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),galaxies.get(0),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Collections.reverse(galaxies);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),galaxies.get(0),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            ascending = !ascending;

        }
    });

    //SEARCHBAR TEXT CHANGE LISTENER
    searchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            //SEARCH FILTER
            adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


        }
    });


    //LISTVIEW ITEM CLICKED
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, adapter.getItem(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

 }
}
```

My content xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
- ActivityMain.xml.
- This is a template layout for our MainActivity.
- Root layout tag is CoordinatorLayout from design support library.
- CordinatorLayout is viewgroup that is a superpowered on framelayout.
- CoordinatorLayout is intended for two primary use cases:
As a top-level application decor or chrome layout
As a container for a specific interaction with one or more child views
- Inside our CordinatorLayout we add : AppBarLayout,FloatingActionButton and include content_main.xml.
- AppBarLayout is vertical LinearLayout that implements scrolling features of material design concept.
- It should be a direct child of CordinatorLayout, otherwise alot of features won't work.
- Inside the AppBarLayout we add our toolbar,which we give a blue color.
- Next we add our Material SearchBar which will give us the searchbar.
- We can specify attributes like style and hint.
- We will add our widgets in our content_main.xml, not here as this is a template layout.
- Finally we have a FloatingActionButton, a class that derives from android.support.design.widget.VisibilityAwareImageButton.
Its the round button you see in our user interface.
-->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tutorials.hp.searchbarlistview.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
             app:mt_hint="Custom hint"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:mt_maxSuggestionsCount="5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchBar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sortBtn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Sort"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is that when i use sort button, it works fine, but only at start. When I use search bar and the use the sort option, its not working

Comment: sure: sort `List<String> galaxies` before passing to your adapter

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you hit filter , array adapter maintains a separate copy of your values , any change that you make to your own copy of list of galaxies won't affect your list, Try using this code to sort your values

```
adapter.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
@Override
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
}
```

});

This will sort the copy maintained by your adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom adapter extending BaseAdapter and pass list into the constructor of your custom adaptor.
you can maintain two different copies of list at your end.
First one will be original list and second one will be the one which you pass to the adapter constructor.

the following link will give you an idea:
[Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)